# MS SQL Stored Procedure for JSON import - Check if input exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following Stored Procedure.

However if "X-Forwarded-For" is empty I would like to retrieve "remote_address" instead.

How can I do this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Table(@payload NVARCHAR(MAX))
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS    
  SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  IF (ISJSON(@payload) != 1) THROW 50001, 'JSON data expected', 1;

  INSERT INTO dbo.Table(IP,Time)  
  SELECT JSONData.IP, getdate()
  FROM OPENJSON (@payload)  
           WITH (  
              IP       varchar(50)  N'$.request.headers."X-Forwarded-For"' 
           )  
  AS JSONData;
GO
```

The line for remote address looks like:

```
              IP       varchar(50)  N'$.transaction.remote_address'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(JSONData.XForwardedForIP, JSONData.RemoteAddressIP), getdate()
FROM OPENJSON (@payload)  
         WITH (  
            XForwardedForIP varchar(50)  N'$.request.headers."X-Forwarded-For"',
            RemoteAddressIP varchar(50)  N'$.transaction.remote_address' 
         )  
AS JSONData;
```

Comment: Oooh!  I like the look of that :D  I'm just out for lunch so will test this afternoon.  Thank you!